LISP - Arrow on 3d polyline to show water flow direction
I will appreciate if someone could help modify this nice LISP written by Stefan and Jonathan that I founded here:
https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/topic/57478-arrow-on-3d-polyline-to-show-water-flow-direction/
This lisp adds arrows symbol to a 3D polyline to show water flow direction (based on Z values).
Is it possible to modify it so instead of arrows created in 2D polylines, all the arrows on a single object will turn to a block with an insertion point in the middle of it.
Thank you very much in advance
This is the lisp:
;Show flow direction
;Stefan M. - 26.07.2015
(defun c:flow ( / *error* ms ss e l key d i n c y p f a p1 p2 p3 ar) ; Variable 'i' localised (Jonathan Handojo)
 (or acDoc (setq acDoc (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object))))
 (setq ms (vlax-get acDoc (if (= 1 (getvar 'cvport)) 'paperspace 'modelspace)))
 (vla-startundomark acDoc)
 
 (defun *error* (msg)
   (and
     msg
     (not (wcmatch (strcase msg) "*CANCEL*,*QUIT*,*EXIT*"))
     (princ (strcat "\nError: " msg))
   )
   (vla-endundomark acDoc)
   (princ)
 )
 (if
   (eq (vla-get-lock (vla-get-activelayer acdoc)) :vlax-true)
   (progn
     (princ "\nCurrent Layer is locked.")
     (exit)
     )
   )
 
 (if
   (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "POLYLINE") (-4 . "&=") (70 . 8)))) ; Modified to multiple selection (Jonathan Handojo)
   (progn
     (or (tblsearch "layer" "arrow") (vla-add (vla-get-layers acDoc) "arrow"))
;;;     (setq e (ssname ss 0) ; Commented (Jonathan Handojo)
;;;           l (vlax-curve-getdistatpoint e (vlax-curve-getendpoint e))
;;;           )
     (initget "Distance Items" 1)
     (setq key (getkword "\nChoose a method [Distance/Items]: ")) ; Modified (Jonathan Handojo)
     (if
       (eq key "Distance")
       (setq d (getdist "\nDistance between arrows: "))
       (setq n (getint  "\nNumber of arrows: "))
       )
     (repeat (setq i (sslength ss)) ; Repeat loop (Jonathan Handojo)
(setq i (1- i) e (ssname ss i) ; Curve details moved here (Jonathan Handojo)
           l (vlax-curve-getdistatpoint e (vlax-curve-getendpoint e))
           )
     (if n (setq d (/ l n)))
     (if d
       (progn
         (setq c 0.0 y (/ d 5.0))
         (while (< (setq c (+ c d)) l)
           (setq p (vlax-curve-getpointatdist e c)
                 f (vlax-curve-getfirstderiv e (vlax-curve-getparamatpoint e p))
                 a (angle '(0.0 0.0) f)
                 p1 (polar p a (if (minusp (caddr f)) (- y) y))
                 p2 (polar p1 (+ a (* pi 0.5)) (* 0.4 y))
                 p3 (polar p1 (- a (* pi 0.5)) (* 0.4 y))
                 ar (vla-Add3DPoly ms
                      (vlax-safearray-fill
                        (vlax-make-safearray vlax-vbDouble '(0 . 8))
                        (append p2 p p3)
                        )
                      )
                 )
           (vla-put-closed ar :vlax-true)
;;;            (vla-put-color ar (if (minusp (caddr f)) acred acyellow))
           (vla-put-layer ar "arrow")
           )
         )
       )
) ; Repeat loop end (Jonathan Handojo)
     ) 
   )
 (*error* nil)
 (princ)
 )

I do not wish to use linetype because I must use 3D polyline and it does not support linetype
